# How to process user selection from custom select dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to know if its possible to process a user's selection from this select dropdown.

I think it uses jquery to style it, but I am not sure if it does the whole procedure of selecting an option and displaying it.

So, do I need to go in and adjust the jquery for this, or can I simply process the user input like you normally would in a default select?

At the moment jquery is not working not sure why, but you can see it here:
http://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/

I hope this was understandable.

```js
! function(e) {
  e.fn.niceSelect = function(t) {
    function s(t) {
      t.after(e("<div></div>").addClass("nice-select").addClass(t.attr("class") || "").addClass(t.attr("disabled") ? "disabled" : "").attr("tabindex", t.attr("disabled") ? null : "0").html('<span class="current"></span><ul class="list"></ul>'));
      var s = t.next(),
        n = t.find("option"),
        i = t.find("option:selected");
      s.find(".current").html(i.data("display") || i.text()), n.each(function(t) {
        var n = e(this),
          i = n.data("display");
        s.find("ul").append(e("<li></li>").attr("data-value", n.val()).attr("data-display", i || null).addClass("option" + (n.is(":selected") ? " selected" : "") + (n.is(":disabled") ? " disabled" : "")).html(n.text()))
      })
    }
    if ("string" == typeof t) return "update" == t ? this.each(function() {
      var t = e(this),
        n = e(this).next(".nice-select"),
        i = n.hasClass("open");
      n.length && (n.remove(), s(t), i && t.next().trigger("click"))
    }) : "destroy" == t ? (this.each(function() {
      var t = e(this),
        s = e(this).next(".nice-select");
      s.length && (s.remove(), t.css("display", ""))
    }), 0 == e(".nice-select").length && e(document).off(".nice_select")) : console.log('Method "' + t + '" does not exist.'), this;
    this.hide(), this.each(function() {
      var t = e(this);
      t.next().hasClass("nice-select") || s(t)
    }), e(document).off(".nice_select"), e(document).on("click.nice_select", ".nice-select", function(t) {
      var s = e(this);
      e(".nice-select").not(s).removeClass("open"), s.toggleClass("open"), s.hasClass("open") ? (s.find(".option"), s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"), s.find(".selected").addClass("focus")) : s.focus()
    }), e(document).on("click.nice_select", function(t) {
      0 === e(t.target).closest(".nice-select").length && e(".nice-select").removeClass("open").find(".option")
    }), e(document).on("click.nice_select", ".nice-select .option:not(.disabled)", function(t) {
      var s = e(this),
        n = s.closest(".nice-select");
      n.find(".selected").removeClass("selected"), s.addClass("selected");
      var i = s.data("display") || s.text();
      n.find(".current").text(i), n.prev("select").val(s.data("value")).trigger("change")
    }), e(document).on("keydown.nice_select", ".nice-select", function(t) {
      var s = e(this),
        n = e(s.find(".focus") || s.find(".list .option.selected"));
      if (32 == t.keyCode || 13 == t.keyCode) return s.hasClass("open") ? n.trigger("click") : s.trigger("click"), !1;
      if (40 == t.keyCode) {
        if (s.hasClass("open")) {
          var i = n.nextAll(".option:not(.disabled)").first();
          i.length > 0 && (s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"), i.addClass("focus"))
        } else s.trigger("click");
        return !1
      }
      if (38 == t.keyCode) {
        if (s.hasClass("open")) {
          var l = n.prevAll(".option:not(.disabled)").first();
          l.length > 0 && (s.find(".focus").removeClass("focus"), l.addClass("focus"))
        } else s.trigger("click");
        return !1
      }
      if (27 == t.keyCode) s.hasClass("open") && s.trigger("click");
      else if (9 == t.keyCode && s.hasClass("open")) return !1
    });
    var n = document.createElement("a").style;
    return n.cssText = "pointer-events:auto", "auto" !== n.pointerEvents && e("html").addClass("no-csspointerevents"), this
  }
}(jQuery);
```

```css
.nice-select {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #e0e7ee;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: both;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left !important;
  /*   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
}
.nice-select:hover {
  border-color: #d0dae5;
}
.nice-select:active,
.nice-select.open,
.nice-select:focus {
  border-color: #88bfff;
}
.nice-select:after {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #90a1b5;
  border-right: 2px solid #90a1b5;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 66% 66%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 66% 66%;
  transform-origin: 66% 66%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  /*     -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out; */
  width: 5px;
}
.nice-select.open:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.nice-select.open .list {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
}
.nice-select.disabled {
  border-color: #e7ecf2;
  color: #90a1b5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.nice-select.disabled:after {
  border-color: #cdd5de;
}
.nice-select.wide {
  width: 100%;
}
.nice-select.wide .list {
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}
.nice-select.right {
  float: right;
}
.nice-select.right .list {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
.nice-select.small {
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 34px;
}
.nice-select.small:after {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
}
.nice-select.small .option {
  line-height: 34px;
  min-height: 34px;
}
.nice-select .list {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(68, 88, 112, 0.11);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-21px);
  /*     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.25), opacity 0.15s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 1.25), opacity 0.15s ease-out; */
  z-index: 9;
}
.nice-select .list:hover .option:not(:hover) {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
.nice-select .option {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  min-height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 29px;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.nice-select .option:hover,
.nice-select .option.focus,
.nice-select .option.selected.focus {
  background-color: #f6f7f9;
}
.nice-select .option.selected {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nice-select .option.disabled {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #90a1b5;
  cursor: default;
}
.no-csspointerevents .nice-select .list {
  display: none;
}
.no-csspointerevents .nice-select.open .list {
  display: block;
}
code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #445870;
  -webkit-hyphens: none;
  -ms-hyphens: none;
  hyphens: none;
  line-height: 1.5;
  -moz-tab-size: 4;
  -o-tab-size: 4;
  tab-size: 4;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: pre;
  word-break: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  font-family: Inconsolata, monospace;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}
/* Code blocks */

pre[class*="language-"] {
  padding: 18px 24px;
  margin: 0 0 24px;
  overflow: auto;
}
:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {
  background: #f6f7f9;
}
/* Inline code */

:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"] {
  padding: 0 2px 1px;
}
.token.comment,
.token.prolog,
.token.doctype,
.token.cdata {
  color: #90a1b5;
}
.token.punctuation {
  color: #999;
}
.namespace {
  opacity: .7;
}
.token.property,
.token.tag,
.token.boolean,
.token.number,
.token.constant,
.token.symbol,
.token.deleted {
  color: #EC4444;
}
.token.selector,
.token.attr-name,
.token.string,
.token.char,
.token.builtin,
.token.inserted {
  color: #4ABF60;
}
.token.operator,
.token.entity,
.token.url,
.language-css .token.string,
.style .token.string {
  color: #a67f59;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.token.atrule,
.token.attr-value,
.token.keyword {
  color: #55a1fb;
}
.token.function {
  color: #DD4A68;
}
.token.regex,
.token.important,
.token.variable {
  color: #e90;
}
.token.important,
.token.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.token.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}
.token.entity {
  cursor: help;
}
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #445870;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: -0.25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 18px;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 0 0 1.6em;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin: 0 0 24px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
  padding-top: 48px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 12px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
a:not(.button) {
  color: #55a1fb;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; */
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
a:not(.button):hover,
a:not(.button):focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #88bfff;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #f3f4f7;
}
::selection {
  background: #f3f4f7;
}
.container {
  margin: 96px auto 60px;
  max-width: 40em;
}
.box {
  background-color: #f6f7f9;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 24px 30px;
}
.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.box:after {
  clear: both;
}
label {
  color: #90a1b5;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 0 2px 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
}
label.right {
  float: right;
}
.button {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  background-color: #55a1fb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; */
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
}
.button:hover,
.button:focus {
  background-color: #4196fb;
}
.button:active,
.button.nice-select.open {
  background-color: #2d8bfa;
}
.button.light {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e0e7ee;
  color: #55a1fb;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-left: 24px;
}
.button.light:hover {
  border-color: #d0dae5;
}
.button.light:active,
.button.light.nice-select.open,
.button.light:focus {
  border-color: #88bfff;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .button {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .button.light {
    margin: 18px 0 0;
  }
}
.header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .header {
    padding: 0 18px;
  }
}
.header p {
  color: #90a1b5;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}
.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
.footer p {
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
.credit {
  color: #90a1b5;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js" integrity="sha256-IGWuzKD7mwVnNY01LtXxq3L84Tm/RJtNCYBfXZw3Je0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="box">
  <label>Wide</label>
  <select class="wide">
    <option data-display="Select">Nothing</option>
    <option value="1">Some option</option>
    <option value="2">Another option</option>
    <option value="3" disabled>A disabled option</option>
    <option value="4">Potato</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you can: http://output.jsbin.com/kocere

Comment: @Mosh, thank you! :)

Comment: @Mosh, could the same go for the jQuery SelectMenu as well? https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#default ...totally novice questions, apologize...

Comment: @Mosh, and by the way, is it fine that this select I added to the snippet uses an earlier version of jquery (1.11.3)? I am not sure whether it is fine to use this, or do I have to upgrade to the new version for it?

Comment: For jQuery `SelectMenu` you need to add a little code. Like this: http://jsbin.com/nuyehe/edit?html,css. Which version are using in your project?

Comment: @Mosh the snippet to my question here utilizes version 1.11.3 of jquery.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but if the version works for you, it's fine.